# Busybox filter string list

Tags: regex, string-manipulation, busybox

Consider I have a list like this:

```
list='item1.service item2.service item3.target item4.service'
```

I need to filter this list to get something as:

```
item1 item2 item4
```

So, there are two things to notice:

1. I need keep only the `.service` items.
2. I need only the "base" names, without the `.service` suffix.

And one more important information: I am running on busybox, where tools are often crippled (e.g.: my `grep` has no support for Perl regexes).

I have been struggling against combinations of `sed` and `grep` and the best I could get is:

```
$ echo $list | grep -io '[a-z0-9\-\_@]*.service' | sed 's/\.service//'
item1
item2
item4
```

but it needs to perform essentially the same match twice for each input, what doesn't look very efficient.
Could anyone suggest any better solution, please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does this have to do with Busybox?

Comment: `sed` does all the job `echo "$list"|sed -r 's/[a-z0-9@_-]+\.target//;s/ +/ /g;s/ /\n/g'`. This works in BusyBox 1.2.1, very old.

Comment: Thanks @Paulo for your response. Unfortunatelly, `sed` doesn't remove the suffix and the generate output is `item1.service` instead of simply `item1` as I need.

Comment: @j4x The `sed` you posted has the command to cut the suffix, just append it to `sed` script `sed -r 's/[a-z0-9@_-]+\.target//;s/\.service//g;s/ +/ /g;s/ /\n/g'`. `g` flag is needed to replace all matches, without it `sed` will replace only the first match.

Comment: Good. IT is devilish to understand but works! @Paulo, please post an answer so I can mark it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list='item1.service item2.service item3.target item4.service'
echo "$list" | sed -r '

# Since the input is only one line, all commands will scan all the pattern space,
# so the commands order matters.

# replace for nothing unwanted text
s/[a-z0-9@_-]+\.target//

# replace for nothing unwanted suffix
# (with 'g' flag the command will replace all occurrences)
s/\.service//g

# squeeze double spaces
s/ +/ /g

# replace space for new line character
s/ /\n/g'
```

I think this will work in all versions of BusyBox's `sed` (could be `awk` too if you have it in your BusyBox).

I just downloaded the latest BusyBox version and ran `make menuconfig` but couldn't
find any reference to Perl regex.